# How to read data from input placed in td by jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been trying to read values from table with a simple structure of

```
<table id='myTable'>
 <tr>
  <td><input id='myId'/><td>
</tr>
</table>
```

But I am failing with something around:

```
 $('#myTable tr').each(function() {
            var Id = $(this).find(".myId").html();
}
```

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: `.` is for class and `#` is for ids. use `.find('#myId')`. Also if you have unique id, why loop? Just use it directly `$('#myId').html()`

Comment: and try `.val()` instead of `.html()`, an input field has a value.

Comment: Id is used for unique approach. If your `td` repeats, give class to the input in it. And find input by class. Or you can search input by tag like `.find("input")`

Comment: @Rajesh the loop is there because I need to collect data from all rows in the table

Comment: @cAMPy having element with same id in every row is bad practice. You should rather use classes.

Comment: Ok, I see now that I am not looping through the rows, I get only data from the first row. If I change for classes instead of id's it will be better, right?

Answer (score 0):

To select by ID you need to use `#`, instead of `.` which is the class selector, e.g.

```
$('#myTable tr').each(function() {
    var Id = $(this).find("#myId").html();
}
```

More information about CSS selectors can be found on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors)